# ByteBuffer vs BufferInputStream

Tags: java, bytebuffer, bufferedinputstream

Would a NIO ByteBuffer consistently offer a faster read performance than an IO BufferedStream?
If so,what would the reason be (keeping aside the multi-threading capbilities of NIO).
I read about minimized copying of the read data in the former case,while bringing the data from disk to application space.
Please help in understanding this - if this is actually true.

Comment: They do different things.

Answer (score 0):

They were made for different purposes.

ByteBuffer - it's just a byte buffer with a lot of convenience methods for manipulate data.

BufferedStream - it's the buffered implementation of InputStream. It's made to buffer data from one InputStream to another.